# Mapping Java type to database type

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I want to set type of my columns from my Java code manually (table is not created yet). `String` should be `text` type in database, and `LocalDate` should be `date` type. Afaik without mappings, `String` will be mapped as `VARCHAR` type.

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "subscribers_service", name = "subscribers")
public class Subscriber {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "subscription_date")
    private LocalDate dateOfSubscription;

}
```

So I want kinda this:

```
    @Id
    @Column(name = "email")
    @DatabaseType(name = "text")
    private String email;
```

I'm using PotsgreSQL. Is it possible? Or I should manually create database with required column types?

Comment: Historically TEXT was for large strings, "memo" fields, not immediately stored with the record, not indexable, and VARCHAR for shorter strings. So it might be worth asking for removing any length limit on VARCHAR (say 255) instead. That might be more feasible too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the database colum types via Java code using the annotation `@Column`

All you have to do is add `columnDefinition` to the annotation

Example

`@Column(name = "email", columnDefinition = "text")`

and

`@Column(name = "subscription_date", columnDefinition = "date")`

Hope this was helpful.